# I'm facing a problem while flashing the image of Raspbian stretch to my SD card

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I Tried to boot Raspbian Stretch on my Raspberry pi Zero W headless. I followed the instructions as given in this link - [How to Flash an SD Card for Raspberry Pi](https://computers.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-flash-an-sd-card-for-raspberry-pi--mac-53600)
After running this Command 
`sudo dd if=/Users/BHOPS/Downloads/2017-11-29-raspbian-stretch.img of=/dev/disk2 bs=2m`
 and entering system password the terminal says Resource busy `dd: /dev/disk2: Resource busy`[image]
Please help me out with it...

Comment: The device is probably automounted... try: `sudo umount /dev/disk2`  ... and then re-try `dd`

Comment: Of course...  it's a Mac and not GNU/Linux... so... just as the instructions you linked to indicate... try: `diskutil umountdisk /dev/disk2`   before writing to the USB stick with `dd`

Comment: Etcher is available for macos.  I would recommend using that to flash the image for anyone not comfortable with `dd`ing things.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted my earlier "answer" which I wrote on a phone - the image is illegible on a phone, and almost on a laptop. `disk2` is part of macOS on many Macs.

`dd` is a powerful command, but **DANGEROUS** - it will happily overwrite almost anything without warning.

The reason it failed is because you are trying to write to a disk with mounted partitions.

You could "fix" this by unmounting, but it is still dangerous. I use the following script, which checks to ensure you are writing to a sensible place. **However** I strongly suggest you install and use `Etcher` which also has safeguards. There have been problems with recent Foundation images (due to the use of incomplete blocks) which `Etcher` handles.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to restore backup to Pi SD card
# 2017-08-26

DSK='disk2'

# Image name (no ext)
IMG='2017-08-16-raspbian-stretch'

# Check for sensible disk
export PTYPE=$(diskutil list  /dev/$DSK | awk '/GUID_partition_scheme/ {print $2}; /Apple/ {print $2}; /Windows_NTFS/ {print $2}' )
if [ "$PTYPE" ]; then
    echo "Disk not a SD Card - Contains "$PTYPE
    exit
elif [ ! /dev/$DSK ]; then
    echo "/dev/$DSK not found"
    exit
fi

echo Ensure SD partitions are unmounted!
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/$DSK

# Check if image exists - else try to uncompress
if [ -s $IMG.img ]; then
    echo $IMG.img exists
elif [ -s $IMG.img.gz ]; then
    echo Copying $IMG.img.gz
    echo Ctl+T to show progress!
    #time  gunzip -k $IMG.img.gz
    time gunzip -kc $IMG.img.gz | sudo dd conv=sync of=/dev/r$DSK bs=4m
    exit
elif [ -s $IMG.zip ]; then
    echo Copying $IMG.zip
    echo Ctl+T to show progress!
    time unzip -p $IMG.zip | sudo dd conv=sync of=/dev/r$DSK bs=4m
    exit
fi

echo please wait - This takes some time
echo Ctl+T to show progress!
time sudo dd conv=sync if=$IMG.img of=/dev/r$DSK bs=4m

exit
```